# Add UILabel to UIToolbar Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a UILabel to UIToolbar, created programmatically using the swift 3.0 language. The toolBar is to accompany the automatic keyboard called when the user is editing a UITextField.This is my function to create the toolbar (called by the viewDidLoad), which includes a 'Done' button, 'Cancel' button, and a space in between:

```
func createToolbar {
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.sizetofit()
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar 
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(EntryViewController.doneButtonTapped))
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(EntryViewController.cancelButtonTapped))
let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
toolBar.setItems([doneButton, space, cancelButton], animated: false)
```

Here is a picture of the loaded toolbar:
[toolBar Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cr60.png)

To create the label, I am using this code:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Example"
let labelAsBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
toolBar.setItems([doneButton, space, cancelButton, labelAsBarButtonItem], animated: false)
}
```

However, this code is not working and does not load the label on the created toolbar.

Comment: Based on the snippet you've posted, it doesn't look like you're doing anything with the toolbar after you instantiate it in `createToolbar`. You'll probably want add toolbar to the view.

Comment: What do you mean by the existing toolbar? If you just want to use that, you can get it from `self.navigationController.toolbar`

Comment: Hello, I edited the post, by existing toolBar I mean the toolBar I created.

Comment: Where should the toolbar sit on the screen?

Comment: The toolbar should sit above the keyboard triggered by clicking on a uitextfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDITED ANSWER

The problem is with the label.
After instanciation, you must draw it with CGRect. so,
add for exemple : `label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y:20, width: 100, height: 50)`

Result:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Example"
label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y:20, width: 100, height: 50)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the code is not working :/. I edited the post to give more detail about the problem, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Hello, thank you. This code worked. Is there anyway to centre the label on the UIToolbar? I am using the flexible-space button which I created, however , it is still not being centred. Perhaps by adjusting the x-value or y-value it might work?

Comment: Nevermind, I have found the answer. I simply used the `sizeToFit()` property.

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Below code works for me, try setting toolbar height to 44 and add it to the view

```
func createToolbar() {
  let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))
  toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
  let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
  let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
  let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
  label.text = "Example"
  label.textAlignment = .center
  label.textColor = view.tintColor
  let customBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
  let rightSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
  toolBar.setItems([doneButton, space, cancelButton, rightSpace, customBarButton], animated: false)
        view.addSubview(toolBar)
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the code is not working, and does not add the label. I edited the post to give more detail about the problem, do you have any recommendations?